# Changing a UITableViewController dynamically via location

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, uitabbarcontroller

I am in the process of building an app, for the record I am using the code from the `ECSlidingView` controller. I would like for my app to use the GPS to pull data from my web interface letting the user know that they can do certain things at a given location. So for example, I have a user go to a store and lets say I want them to make a payment at that location, it will given them that option. Or if the store doesn't offer payment through the app, I disable that. What would be a good way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `CoreLocation` but you might have trouble getting accurate location inside (it will most probably use wifi or cellular info so the accuracy might not be what you expect). Then, when you get the location, issue a request to your service passing latitude and longiude you receive from `CoreLocation`. There, you should search by location to retrieve possible matches - consider returning muliple store infos for nearby stores due to the accuracy issues.

Comment: He doesn't actually have any choice, he will have to use CoreLocation. Your points about the accuracy and showing multiple stores though are spot on.